# http4s Router default return method not allowed

Tags: http4s

org.http4s.server.Router has a .orNotFound, but instead of this I want to return 405 methodNotAllowed. How can I do that? Please provide example. I saw the .orElse but not sure how to use it.

```
Router(
  "/api" -> myroutes() 
).orElse(.??.)
```

Thanks